# Does filter,map, and reduce in Python create a new copy of list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, higher-order-functions

Using `Python 2.7`. Let us say we have `list_of_nums = [1,2,2,3,4,5]`
and we want to remove all occurrences of 2. We can achieve it by
`list_of_nums[:] = filter(lambda x: x! = 2, list_of_nums)` or  `list_of_nums = filter(lambda x: x! = 2, list_of_nums)`.

Is this an "in-place" substitution? Also, are we creating a copy of list when we use filter?

Comment: Try it, use [```is```](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) to see if they are the same **thing**.  If you try to assign the return value do you get ```None```?  Or use [```id()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) before and after, is it the same?

Comment: @wwii Using `id` may even convince him more.

Comment: From the docs: [*Construct a **list** from those elements of iterable for which function returns true...*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

Comment: "Also, are we creating a copy of list when we use filter?" No, it just iterates over the list (or other iterable) arg. FWIW, in Python 3, `filter` and `map` return iterators, not lists.

Comment: Note that the in-place version with `list_of_nums[:]` is slower than re-binding the new list to the `list_of_nums` name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list_of_nums[:] = filter(lambda x: x != 2, list_of_nums)
```

and

```
list_of_nums = filter(lambda x: x != 2, list_of_nums)
```

are two different operations that end up with *mostly* the same result.

In both cases,

```
filter(lambda x: x != 2, list_of_nums)
```

returns either a new list containing items that match the filter (in Python 2), or an iterable over `list_of_nums` that returns the same items (in Python 3).

The first case,

```
list_of_nums[:] = filter(lambda x: x != 2, list_of_nums)
```

then deletes all items from `list_of_nums` and replaces them with the items from the new list or iterable.

The second case,

```
list_of_nums = filter(lambda x: x != 2, list_of_nums)
```

assigns the new list to the variable `list_of_nums`.

The time when this makes a difference is this:

```
def processItemsNotTwo_case1(list_of_nums):
    list_of_nums[:] = filter(lambda x: x != 2, list_of_nums)
    # do stuff here
    # return something

def processItemsNotTwo_case2(list_of_nums):
    list_of_nums = filter(lambda x: x != 2, list_of_nums)
    # do stuff here
    # return something

list1 = [1,2,2,3,4,5]
processItemsNotTwo_case1(list1)
list2 = [1,2,2,3,4,5]
processItemsNotTwo_case2(list2)
```

With this code, `list1` ends up with the new contents `[1,3,4,5]`, whereas `list2` ends up with the original contents `[1,2,2,3,4,5]`.